# Plot straight line over a interval in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to plot a straight line over a interval. For example, I have two variables: h and Time. When Time is between 0 to 0.56, the h value is 0.25. I need it to be a straight line. Similarly, for other points.When i use the function plot(Time,h), the lines are connected. I don't want this.

Need some guidance on this..

It looks like this:
[image]

What I have tried so far?

```
function PlotH(Time,h)
    for i=2:size(Time)
        x = h(i)*ones(1,Time(i));
        hold on;
    end
    plot(x)
    ymax = max(h);
    xlim([1 max(Time)]);
    ylim([-0.5 ymax+0.5]);
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Rate')
end
```

Comment: This should get you started:
`plot(Time,h,L)`. And set `L=`, based on what you want.
`L = '-'` line,
`L = '.'` points,
`L = '--'` dashed line,
`L = 'o'` empty points.
Also, ever tried pressing F1 while hovering over a function in Matlab? quite helpful

Comment: still not able to do it..

Comment: what is the code you used to plot the figure?

Comment: that, as noted in my first comment will give you a connected line. If you want separate points you can use `'.'`.
Try using `plot(Time(1:5,h(1:5),'-');hold on;plot(Time(6:end),h(6:end),'.')`

Comment: i need straightline over a interval..

Comment: So find the interval for which you want the straight lines (and points), then use that to plot. Remember that plotting is just a visual tool and unless Matlab "knows" what are your conditions, it/you won't be able to visualise (plot) your result.

Comment: You may also wish to use the following approach:`scatter(Time,h)` plot all all data (or `plot(Time,h,'.')`) and then plot another time using `plot(Time,h,'-')` the regions you wish to connect.

Comment: simple, within a region, it is straight value, another region another value... no connection..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even simpler, just use [`stairs`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html). This will take the value from the *start* of the interval, so to match the example and use the value from the *end* of each interval you'd need to shift `h` and `Time` relative to each other, e.g. `stairs(Time(2:end), h(1:end-1))`.

Comment: I'll admit I too implemented this myself several times before I discovered `stairs` existed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question:

```
function PlotH(Time,h)
    for i=2:size(Time,1)
        plot([Time(i-1), Time(i)],[h(i), h(i)])
        hold on;
    end
    ymax = max(h);
    xlim([1 max(Time)]);
    ylim([-0.5 ymax+0.5]);
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Rate')
end
```